# MVC - Check drowdownlist value in real time

Tags: asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

How can I check the dropdownlist selectedvalue in real time in MVC, everytime the selected value is changed?

```
<div class="modal-body">
     Ticket Category:     @Html.DropDownList("TicketCategory", (SelectList)ViewBag.TicketCategory, "--Select Category--")
    </div>
    @if(TicketCategory.SelectedValue == "")
    {
        //do
    }
    else
    {
        //do 
    }
```

In this case the TicketCategory is not found, am I missing some conversion or do I have to retrieve the element?

Comment: Handle Jquery `onchage()` event for that specific `dropdownlist`. And if you want to do some server side actions, then you can use `AJAX GET/POST` in that onchange event.

Comment: Is `TicketCategory` a property of your model - in which case it needs to be `@if(Model.TicketCategory == "")` or is it just a `ViewBag` property - in which case use `ViewBag.TicketCategory`. And you cannot name the `SelectList` the same as the property your binding to, so change one or the other.

Comment: @StephenMuecke no, it's just a ViewBag as I have a different model in the view.

Comment: you can add javascript function @Html.DropDownList("TicketCategory", (SelectList)ViewBag.TicketCategory, "--Select Category--", new { onchange = "UpdateProduct(this);" )

Comment: @abbasGaliyakot and what does the UpdateProduct(this); do exactly?

Comment: If your wanting to perform some action when the an option is selected you need to handle the `.change()` event in javascript/jquery. Razor code is server side code and knows nothing about what happens on the client

Comment: UpdateProduct(this) is just a example to  javascript function.

Comment: What is it that you actually want to do when the user selects an option?

Comment: @StephenMuecke display textboxes accordingly

Comment: Just add a script - `$('#TicketCategory').change(function() { if ($(this).val()) { // do something } else { // do something else } });`

Answer (score 0):

For DropDownList you have an extra parameter for declaring some htmlAttributes.

From my point of view you always must flag your inputs that you're listening to with some js-smth class.

RAZOR:

```
<div class="modal-body js-modalBody">
     Ticket Category:     @Html.DropDownList("TicketCategory", (SelectList)ViewBag.TicketCategory, "--Select Category--",  new { @class = "js-ticketCategory" })
</div>
```

After this you can add a script tag, listening to change event of the input. 
Assuming that you search for a value that is "3", here is your code.

```
<script>

$('.js-modalBody').on('change', '.js-ticketCategory', function (ev) {
    if ($(ev.currentTarget).val() == "3") {
        // do something 
    } else {
        // do something else 
    }
});

</script>
```

P.S: Having javascript in your views isn't a beatiful approach.